# Dockerfiles and COPY/ADD

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've been trying to build an application called Crowd for a client but my Docker experience isn't great.

This is the [DockerHub page](https://hub.docker.com/r/blacklabelops/crowd)

Now, if I run `docker run -d -p 8095:8095 --name crowd blacklabelops/crowd`

It runs and I have no problem, but if copy and paste their [Dockerfile](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blacklabelops-legacy/crowd/master/Dockerfile)

I get an error telling me that **splash.xml** doesn't exist. My understanding is that the `ADD` command in Dockerfile copies files from the source into the container. But obviously I don't have those files because I'm just running the Dockerfile.

So if the `docker run` command is running based on that Dockerfile, how would the Dockerfile work as a standalone? Please help me understand. Many thanks.

Comment: The Dockerfile is source code.  An image is a compiled binary.

Comment: you should clone the repo, then build the docker image, eg

```
git clone https://github.com/blacklabelops-legacy/crowd.git  my-crowd
cd my-crowd
docker build -t my-image .
```

the docker file use some resource in this git repo

Answer (score 2):

- `Dockerfile` contains instructions on how to build an image. Note that in many cases, these instructions include copying (adding) files into the built image.
- `docker run` runs a complete, built image.

If you wish to build from the `Dockerfile` source, you should probably clone/download the entire repository, and then `docker build` locally.